# What's the highest performance Socket 478 processor at 133MHz FSB?

Tags: performance, cpu, upgrade

Looking to upgrade an older box that has an Asus P4S8X-MX mobo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That'd be the **[Intel® Pentium® 4 Processor Extreme Edition 3.40 GHz (Gallatin)](http://processorfinder.intel.com/details.aspx?sSpec=SL7CH)** 3.4 GHz, 800 FSB, HT.

Now this CPU is also "extreme" in price (i've seen offers for **[$495](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16819116027)**) and since it's such an old computer i wouldn't invest too much money. The **[Intel® Pentium® 4 530 (Prescott)](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16819116027)**  3.0GHz HT, 1MB L2 for $80 looks rather reasonable.

Also keep in mind, these high-powered Prescott and Gallatin CPUs require decent cooling, so if the original CPU was some Celeron, the original heatsink and fan may not suffice.

Check the list of all supported CPUs on the Asus P4S8X-MX [here](http://www.cpu-upgrade.com/mb-ASUS/P4S8X-MX.html).

Comment: For that cost for an older P4 processor, you can get a new Motherboard, Quad-core CPU and 8GB of ram.  (Phenom 2, AMD 785 MB if you need video)

Comment: yep, 500 dollar is ridiculous :)

Comment: Indeed. Pentium 4 was a horrible chip and never reached the frequencies Intel hoped for. You shouldn't expect great improvements from even the best P4 compared to the an older one. I would definitely put the money towards a full cpu/mobo/ram upgrade later.

Comment: @bobince - this not exactly accurate, the Prescott HT CPU is quite a performer compared to the Northwood (nevermind the Willamette), however, this performance comes at the price of pretty high power consumption and massive cooling (hence the nickname P4 Spaceheater :).

Comment: +1 and accepted; thanks for the cpu-upgrade.com link. And excellent discussion. Good point about $80 being most of the way to a mobo/cpu combo. (Drat, Fry's website is down atm.) I just hate throwing away good PCB and silicon.

Comment: you got to be very lucky to find a P4 Extreme for a low price, some Prescott should do you fine. i just refurbished an old HP with a P4 2.8 GHz HT, spent $30 on 1 GB RAM, threw in some spare parts (a 250 GB 7k2 sata HDD and a 256 MB Radeon x600) ... this is still a fine machine.

Comment: Sweet, found a Pentium 4 HT 3.2E (Prescott) on ebay for $31.43 shipped. Thanks again everyone!! Gotta say, SU users are friendlier than the savages on SO. =)

Comment: you're most welcome :)

Comment: Hey do you guys know if these mobile Prescotts will work? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Intel_Pentium_4_microprocessors#Prescott_.2890_nm.29 They're not listed on cpu-upgrade.com but they appear to have the same socket, FSB, and voltage as the procs listed on cpu-upgrade...

Comment: although termed 'Mobile' P4 HT by Intel, it's actaully the same as the desktop CPU, so it should work, any particular reason for using this CPU instead?

Comment: Oh I hadn't yet decided if I was gonna use it, but it reaches spec'd frequency with only 533MHz FSB. And it could be nifty to utilize frequency scaling (SpeedStep) and save some power. Anyway, I thought my mobo didn't support 200MHz on the FSB, but it turns out that it does. So I'm gonna stick with the processor you helped me pick out earlier. Thanks!